# Fractal dimension of the Cantor Set

Tags: general-topology, fractals

How can we get or prove that the 'fractal dimension' of the Cantor set is $\log_{3} (2)$?

I know how to prove by evaluating the poles of  $f(s)= \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{n-1} 3^{-sn}$, and then I take the real pat of the poles which is $\log _{3} (2)$ with complex period $ \frac{2\pi i}{\log 3}$.

Comment: This is a standard argument.  A simple google search turned up: http://www.missouriwestern.edu/orgs/momaa/ChrisShaver-CantorSetPaper4.pdf

Comment: It seems you are evaluating the complex dimensions of this fractal (in the sense of Lapidus).  Is that what you mean by "fractal dimension"??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given an $r>0$, let $N_r(X)$ be the smallest number of balls of radius $r$ that it takes to cover $X$. The fractal dimension of $X$ is
$$
\inf\{d:\limsup_{r\to0}\;r^dN_r(x)=0\}\tag{1}
$$
Considering the "middle-thirds" construction of $C$, $N_r(C)=2^k$ when $r=3^{-k}$. Using $(1)$, we want to find the infimum of $d$ so that $\limsup\limits_{k\to\infty}\; 3^{-kd}2^k=0$, and that is $d=\frac{\log(2)}{\log(3)}$.